# Dynamic cast in Kotlin

Tags: java, casting, kotlin

I want to cast `Any` to `Int` by using `KClass<Int>`, having a `KClass<Int>` and a `Any` which is actually `Int`.

```
fun <T> cast(any: Any, clazz: KClass<*>): T = clazz.java.cast(any) 

cast(0, Int::class)
```

However, I got this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int

Do you know any solution except `any as Int`?

Comment: You need to use kotlin reflection for this somehow. Java reflection won't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to change your code to

```
fun <T: Any> cast(any: Any, clazz: KClass<out T>): T = clazz.javaObjectType.cast(any)
```

### Explanation

Because the type of the parameter `any` is `Any`, it's always a reference type and primitives will be boxed. For the second parameter, it seems that Kotlin reflection will prefer primitive types to reference types, which is why `Int::class.java` will default to `ìnt`, not `Integer`. By using `javaObjectType` we force the usage of the boxed reference type.

### Alternative

You could also use the following function definition:

```
inline fun <reified T: Any> cast(any: Any): T = T::class.javaObjectType.cast(any) 

// usage

cast<Int>(0)
```

Comment: what about `inline fun <reified T:Any> Any.cast() = this as? T`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @voddan, Java reflection does not work here. It's because, from Java point of view, there is no relation between `java.lang.Integer` and `kotlin.Int`.

Kirill Rakhman 's answer works very well for non-nullable type. But we cannot have T::class if T is nullable. So I suggest the following to deal with nullable type (I am not sure why the question say any solution except `as`...)

```
inline fun <reified T> cast(any: Any?): T = any as T
```

Usage

```
val l32: Number = cast(32L)
val ln1: Number? = cast(null) // works
val ln2: Number = cast(null) // fails at runtime
```