# how to get bundle in existing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to get my bundle after i pass it in existing fragment without recreating it.I'm just showing and hiding my fragments. Methods `onResume()` not calls, after `transaction.commitNow()` . I thought about method `update()` in fragment, but i can't create it in android `Fragment.class`. How can i notify my existing fragment, that bundle have passed?

My navigator method in which i pass bundle

navigator:

```
  @PublishedApi
internal fun goTo(tag: String,
                  keepState: Boolean,
                  withCustomAnimation: Boolean,
                  args: Bundle,
                  backStrategy: BackStrategy
                  ){
    if(activeTag == tag){
        return
    }

    if(!fragmentMap.containsKey(tag) || !keepState) {
        val fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, tag)
        if (!args.isEmpty) {
            fragment.arguments = args
        }

        if (!keepState) {
            val weakFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
            weakFragment?.let {
                fragmentManager.inTransaction {
                    remove(weakFragment)
                }
            }
        }
        fragmentManager.inTransaction {
            addOpenAnimation(this, withCustomAnimation)
            add(containerId, fragment, tag)
        }
        fragmentMap.put(tag, Screen(fragment, backStrategy))

        if (activeTag == null) {
            rootTag == tag
        }
    }else{
        val fragment = fragmentMap[tag]?.fragment
        if(!args.isEmpty){
            fragment?.arguments = args
        }
        fragmentMap.put(tag, Screen(fragment!!, backStrategy))

        if (activeTag == null) {
            rootTag == tag
        }
    }
    fragmentManager.inTransaction {
        addOpenAnimation(this, withCustomAnimation)
        fragmentMap
                .filter {
                    it.key != tag
                }
                .forEach {
                    hide(it.value.fragment)
                }
        show(fragmentMap[tag]?.fragment)
        commit()
    }
    activeTag = tag
    invokeFragmentChangeListener(tag)

    fragmentMap.replaceValue(tag, fragmentMap[tag])


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get bundle in a fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ....
}
```

or just call your own method in fragment:

```
public void notifyBundleUpdated() {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I can't . All my fragments extends from android-support Fragment.class. I don't have permission to my own methods

Comment: You can add your own methods into your class

Comment: i know, but i cant call it from `fragment` in `goTo` , because type of it is `supportFragment`

Comment: You might like [Dynamic cast in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41219748/3166697) and [How to check “instanceof ” class in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44098780/3166697)